# Working with user-defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on something I am trying to create a user defined function named Employee_Name. Pass an Employee Id as a parameter.

This is what I have so far :

```
Create function Employee_name (
@EmployeeID int 
 )
 Return Table
 as 
 Return(
         Select * From Employees
    Where Employee_name = @EmplyeeId)
 go
 SELECT * FROM Employee_name
```

But I am not  thinking I am doing this right because where the return table is mark with red. Which means an error. I am still learning this, its kinda confusing for me. I am woundering if the return table should be only a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an Employee ID to your user defined function

```
SELECT * FROM Employee_name (1)
```

Also it should be `RETURNS TABLE`. So

```
CREATE FUNCTION Employee_name 
(
    @EmployeeID int 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT * FROM Employees
    WHERE Employee_name = @EmployeeID
)
GO

SELECT * FROM Employee_name (1)
```

You might have some naming collision between the name of your function and the name of the field in the `Employees` table though (both appear to be called `Employee_name`)

Answer (score 2):

`Return Table` should be `Returns Table`

Answer (score 1):

change it to :

```
Create function Employee_name (
@EmployeeID int 
 )
 Returns Table
 as 
 Return(
         Select * From Employees
    Where Employee_name = @EmplyeeId)
 go
```

and in code :

```
select * from Employee_name (1)
```